# Mutliple tests fail for a drag, but timedDrag works fine - why?

Tags: flutter

This is my tests setup:

```dart
void main() {
  setUpAll(() {
    ...
  });

  group('BehaviorTests', () {
    testWidgets(...);
    testWidgets(...);
    testWidgets(...);
  });
}
```

I use inside them one of the below functions:

```dart
Future<void> scrollToBottom(WidgetTester tester, Finder scrollWidget) async {
    const screenBottomY = -9999.0;
    await tester.timedDrag(
      scrollWidget,
      const Offset(0, screenBottomY),
      const Duration(milliseconds: 100), // lower values make tests fail
    );
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();
}
```

or

```dart
Future<void> scrollToBottom(WidgetTester tester, Finder scrollWidget) async {
     const screenBottomY = -9999.0;
     await tester.drag(scrollWidget, const Offset(0, screenBottomY));
     await tester.pumpAndSettle();
}
```

And there's a surprisingly huge difference. If there's one `testWidgets(...);`, used `scrollToBottom()` doesn't matter. But for multiple, all but one fail for the `drag` one. `timedDrag` makes all tests to pass.

When I look at what's inside widgets during failed tests it turns out that a state which I change in StatefulWidget after scroll to the bottom, didn't cause build() to finish yet - widget values are from the point in time before the state change.

What is going on under the hood? Have anybody experienced that?